# Database consistency check failed

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do `mysqldbcompare` for database that I just moved, but getting `Database consistency check failed.`, I also did another `mysqldump` and used `diff` and it shows that database are `consistent` but still I'd like to understand why `mysqldbcompare` said: `Database consistency check failed.`

```
$ mysqldbcompare --server1=XXX --server2=XXX openx:openx --run-all-tests --disable-binary-logging
# server1 on XXX: ... connected.
# server2 on XXX: ... connected.
# Checking databases openx on server1 and openx on server2
#
#                                                   Defn    Row     Data   
# Type      Object Name                             Diff    Count   Check  
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# TABLE     ox_account_preference_assoc             pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_account_user_assoc                   pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_account_user_permission_assoc        pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_accounts                             pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_acls                                 pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_acls_channel                         pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_ad_category_assoc                    pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_ad_zone_assoc                        pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_affiliates                           pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_affiliates_extra                     pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_agency                               pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_application_variable                 pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_audit                                pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_banner_vast_element                  pass    pass    SKIP    
#
# No primary key found.

# TABLE     ox_banners                              pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_campaigns                            pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_campaigns_trackers                   pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_category                             pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_channel                              pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_clients                              pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_data_bkt_a                           pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_data_bkt_a_var                       pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_data_bkt_c                           pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_data_bkt_m                           pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_data_bkt_r                           pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_data_bkt_vast_e                      pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_data_intermediate_ad                 pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_data_intermediate_ad_connection      pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_data_intermediate_ad_variable_value  pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_data_raw_ad_click                    pass    pass    SKIP    
#
# No primary key found.

# TABLE     ox_data_raw_ad_impression               pass    pass    SKIP    
#
# No primary key found.

# TABLE     ox_data_raw_ad_request                  pass    pass    SKIP    
#
# No primary key found.

# TABLE     ox_data_raw_tracker_impression          pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_data_raw_tracker_variable_value      pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_data_summary_ad_hourly               pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_data_summary_ad_zone_assoc           pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_data_summary_channel_daily           pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_data_summary_zone_impression_history pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_database_action                      pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_ext_market_advertiser                pass    pass    SKIP    
#
# No primary key found.

# TABLE     ox_ext_market_assoc_data                pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_ext_market_campaign_pref             pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_ext_market_general_pref              pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_ext_market_plugin_variable           pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_ext_market_setting                   pass    pass    SKIP    
#
# No primary key found.

# TABLE     ox_ext_market_stats                     pass    pass    SKIP    
#
# No primary key found.

# TABLE     ox_ext_market_web_stats                 pass    pass    SKIP    
#
# No primary key found.

# TABLE     ox_ext_market_website_pref              pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_images                               pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_log_maintenance_forecasting          pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_log_maintenance_priority             pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_log_maintenance_statistics           pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_password_recovery                    pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_placement_zone_assoc                 pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_preferences                          pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_session                              pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_stats_vast                           pass    pass    SKIP    
#
# No primary key found.

# TABLE     ox_targetstats                          pass    pass    SKIP    
#
# No primary key found.

# TABLE     ox_tracker_append                       pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_trackers                             pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_upgrade_action                       pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_userlog                              pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_users                                pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_variable_publisher                   pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_variables                            pass    pass    pass    
# TABLE     ox_zones                                pass    pass    pass   

# Database consistency check failed.
#
# ...done
$
```

Comment: I think this question belongs on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: MODs: if this is wrong place, please move it.